# Run Drupal project

Tags: drupal, module, installation

I installed a Drupal project which was developed not by me.

How could I see the project result? I mean the actual site?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some checks you can do like.

Visit on front page via click on home in menu or in url `localhost/fivedaydiscovery`

To check what types of content types are created go to `admin>structure>content types`

To get all data go to `admin>content`

To create data for specific content typpe go to `admin>content>Add content`

To check menu links go to `structure>menus` and check links in specific menu.

To check dynamic pages and blocks  go to `structure>views` and `structure>blocks` .

Overall if it has /sitemap.xml then you can check pages and their backend functionality.